# How do I give certain users access to specific Wordpress pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions

I've been searching for a good answer to this question for years and I wanted to ask it here. I've even raised the question on Wordpress forums to no avail.

Is there a way to give certain users access to specific pages on Wordpress? For example, I may want a school teacher to edit only their personal page and the classroom's pages, but let the principal edit anything.

I've searched for a plugin which can get close, but the only ones I found are terrible. They're complicated, unreliable, aren't secure (according to WordPress), and cause other problems on the site.

Most CMS programs come with a feature to limit (or grant) access to certain pages or groups of pages based on the user. Can Wordpress do this?

Thanks!
Brendan

Comment: It sounds like your best bet is something geared towards authors for magazines etc. I can't give a specific example but I know I've seen solutions in the past geared up to allow people to edit specifc pages &/or page types, with an admin having "editorial" control over all submitted updates. Alternatively, you'd probably be best of considering using buddy press and some custom coding, which is something I've worked on fairly recently. However, the depth of that is not something that could be explained on SO.

Comment: You can use basic php to check for user permission, and if not valid, redirect them... (Try using the wordpress php function called `current_user_can()`)

Comment: Perhaps you could use my previous question: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/266582/119355